# How to break a word at a given length (without a hyphen)?

Tags: hyphenation

The problem is to get

[image]

The question is justified. The answer is right flush. The dimensions of the rectangle are 5cm and 4cm. The length of the question is unknown.

Manually

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \def\quest{1/(4.2+5.4)-(3.5+4.7)\\/9} 
  \def\ans{-0.806944444} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large] 
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-4);
\node[align=justify,text width =5cm-1ex,
      anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (qu) {\quest};
\node[align=right,text width =5cm-1ex,
      anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (an) at (qu.south west) {\ans}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I get

[image]

**But how to get this automatically ?**

**Update-information**

The same question was asked on the list pgf/tikz. Mark Wibrow (who worked on pgfmath, and other parts of pgf) gave a beautiful solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\showsum#1{\ifx#1=\par\hfill\else#1\hskip0.1ex 
minus0.5ex\expandafter\showsum\fi}
\tikzset{calculator screen/.style={
    inner sep=2pt,
    fill=blue!20,
    font=\huge\tt,
    execute at begin node={\parindent=0pt\hsize=5cm\vbox to4cm\bgroup},
    execute at end node=\vfill\egroup
}}

\tikz\node[calculator screen]
    {\showsum 1/(4.2+5.4)-(3.5+4.7)/9 +3+2+1= -.80694444};

\end{document}
```

Very impressive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply add a zero skip between any two tokens and set ragged right the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcinput}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \hspace{0pt} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

  \def\quest{\calcinput{1/(4.2+5.4)-(3.5+4.7)/9}}
  \def\ans{\calcinput{-0.806944444}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large\ttfamily]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-4);
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
      anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (qu) {\quest};
\node[align=right,text width =5cm,
      anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (an) at (qu.south west) {\ans};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large\ttfamily]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,-4);
\node[align=flush left,text width =4cm,
      anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (qu) {\quest};
\node[align=right,text width =4cm,
      anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (an) at (qu.south west) {\ans};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The window width should be an integer multiple of .5em in the monospaced font, in my opinion.

Comment: Fine! but "I'd simply add a zero skip between any two tokens" is not easy for me. I'm not a great TeX(pert) and I know nothing about xparse. Perhaps I may stop working TikZ only to discover a new world _alter mundus :)_

Comment: @Altermundus I simply process the input adding `\hspace{0pt}` after each token; so `\calcinput{1+2}` becomes `1\hspace{0pt}+\hspace{0pt}+2\hspace{0pt}` when fed to the text processing done by `\node`. There are various "old-world" LaTeX ways to do it: with `expl3` it's embarassingly easy. :)

Comment: Yes I see. The code is very light. Very impressive